# Disabling IDFA in Firebase Analytics conflicts with Google Analytics

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, idfa, gdprconsentform

We are developing an app in iOS and using GA & FA at the same time. To comply with Apple's ATT, we would like to disable IDFA collection according to user consent.

According to Firebase, **To disable IDFA collection in Firebase Analytics, we have to switch to AnalyticsWithoutAdidSupport framework from Analytics. However, when I try to switch it, it conflicts with Google Analytics.**

Has anyone had the same issue? How could this be solved?